# package Shell: System commands doesn't work with Centos 7.4

Tags: linux, perl, perl-module

Shell module, Shell.pm, does not seem to run shell commands with Centos 7.4.

For instance following script is OK with Centos 6.4:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Shell qw(ps);

$cmd=ps;
print  $cmd . "\n";
```

Result is as expected:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
29090 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
29325 pts/1    00:00:00 test.pm
29326 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

But with Centos 7.4

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I /usr/share/perl5/CPAN

use Shell qw(ps);

$cmd=ps;
print  $cmd . "\n";
```

Result is:

```
ps
```

If i add to the previous script:

```
cat("/etc/passwd");
```

Following error is raised:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::cat called at ./test.pm line 10
```

With a real script none of system commands are well interpreted. Should I  rewrite everything with `system('command')`!?

Comment: Try taking out the space after `-I`, I think you are effectively losing the directory you are trying to add here because only a single option string is supported on the shebang line.

Comment: And as usual, `use strict; use warnings;` yada yada.

Comment: Works for me with CentOS 7.4.1708. How did you install Shell.pm?

Comment: Removing space after -I has no effect

Comment: Same script is OK on a previous version of Centos. Maybe troubles with Perl installation. I am going to see the admin !

Comment: You realize that this "[shouldn't be used for production programs](http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Shell-0.73/Shell.pm)" ?  Don't "_rewrite [...] with `system`_" -- use another module, out of almost half-dozen well established ones.

Comment: Perl is Installed with Centos kickstart, CPAN with yum

Answer (score 0):

Finally I succeeded to make it work !
Installation was not quite good.

I had to run :

```
cpan App::cpanminus
```

then

```
cpanm Shell
```